# Getting all the occurrences of a substring within a string

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I get all the occurrences of a substring within a string in PostgreSQL?

I have this string for an ID:

```
BS Score xxxxxxx075SCxxxBS Score xxxxxxx062SCxxxBS Score xxxxxxx115SCxxx
```

And I would like to get the numbers in the string for the ID, so the result can look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_matches`:

```
select id intl, regexp_replace(v[1], '^0+', '') values from tbl 
cross join regexp_matches(id, '(\d+)', 'g') v
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/L4Poelh2).